# Getting error when i update repository item

Tags: atg

I want to update the repository property name but getting error.
below is the code which used.

```
final MutableRepository mutableRepository = (MutableRepository) getUserAuthorizationRepository();
MutableRepositoryItem repoItem = mutableRepository.getItemForUpdate(groupId, NCRConstants.GROUP);
    repoItem.setPropertyValue(Constants.UPDATED_BY_NAME,(ServletUtil.getCurrentUserProfile().getRepositoryId()));
           repoItem.setPropertyValue(Constants.UPDATED_DATE, new java.util.Date());
           mutableRepository.updateItem(repoItem);
```

and below error witch I am getting.

```
<Jan 17, 2019 1:15:59 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@1521606105[app:ncrlink_development module:/myncr path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to set property named updatedBy (Authorization Repository:group:13400001)  with value = SS185613 (class=class java.lang.String).  The type should be interface atg.repository.RepositoryItem.
        at atg.repository.RepositoryItemImpl.setPropertyValue(RepositoryItemImpl.java:229)
        at atg.adapter.gsa.GSAItem.setPropertyValue(GSAItem.java:1578)
        at com.ncr.myncr.profile.services.GroupPermissionTools.deleteUpdate(GroupPermissionTools.java:1354)
        at com.ncr.myncr.profile.services.GroupPermissionTools.deleteGroup(GroupPermissionTools.java:800)
        at com.ncr.myncr.profile.formhandlers.GroupPermissionFormHandler.handleDeleteGroup(GroupPermissionFormHandler.java:334)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: can you share the xml definition for the properties ?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to set the value of "updatedBy" property to a `String` when it is expecting a `RepositoryItem`.  Will need to see the repository definition file as per the above comment.